# function return true after setTimeout (shouldComponentUpdate)

Tags: reactjs

I want a function to `return true` after a Timeout. Can this be done?

I want to use that in reacts `shouldComponentUpdate()` Method. When returned `true` the Component will be rendered. I want it to be rendered after a Timeout.

what i have found so far is this, but it does not work as expected:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(true);
    }, 3000);
  });
  return promise;
}
```

`shouldComponentUpdate()` should `return true` after 3 seconds.

Comment: What's your purpose of doing that? `shouldComponentUpdate` should be synchronous.

Comment: Are your trying to do something like a polling?

Comment: i want to delay the render so i can animate the component. and if the component got updated during this delay i want to reset it instead of rerendering mutliple times.

Answer (score 1):

`shouldComponentUpdate` must return a boolean immediately. It should be synchronous and fast.

Usually if you want to have some real DOM manipulations like an animation, you can do that in `componentDidUpdate()`.

But it seems that you want the animation **before** the re-render. If your component is depending on props purely, The easiest way is to put the animation code in `componentWillReceiveProps()`, and simply return `false` in `shouldComponentUpdate()`. After the animation you call a `this.forceUpdate()` to force re-render.

Another way I can imagine is to wrap your component with another component. When you have an update then parent will hold the changes for 3 secs and do the animation. After that, the parent pass down the new props to the child.

(For the solution 1, use `shouldComponentUpdate` instead of `componentWillReceiveProps` will also work, but `componentWillReceiveProps` looks better to me)